# flip arguments to Elm function call

Tags: elm

I am trying to modify [the Elm example that shows a single spacer](http://elm-lang.org/edit/examples/Elements/Spacer.elm) so that it renders multiple spacers of different colors:

```
import Color exposing (red, blue, yellow)
import Graphics.Element exposing (Element, color, spacer, flow, right)


colors = [ yellow, red, blue ]

presentColors : List Element
presentColors = List.map (color ??? (spacer 30 30)) colors

main : Element
main =
  flow right presentColors
```

However as you can see the function `color` takes the color argument first and so I cannot create a partially applied version of it for `List.map` to use.

So how can I flip the arguments to `color` so that it can be partially applied?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As of Elm 0.19, `flip` is no longer [included by default](https://github.com/elm/compiler/blob/master/docs/upgrade-instructions/0.19.0.md#functions-removed). The docs recommend named helper functions instead.

---

Go to [the Elm (pre v0.19) libraries page](http://elm-lang.org/Libraries.elm). Press [Standard Libraries](http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm-lang/core/2.0.1/). In the search box, type in `flip` and click [the function that comes up](http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm-lang/core/2.0.1/Basics#flip). That'll give you the documentation for

> `flip : (a -> b -> c) -> b -> a -> c`
> Flip the order of the first two arguments to a function.

With which you can do

```
flip color (spacer 30 30)
```

which is the same thing as

```
\c -> color c (spacer 30 30)
```

Comment: Sometimes parentheses are useful. For example, `(flip color) (spacer 30 30)`.

Comment: Fyi flip, curry, and uncurry were removed from Elm 0.19. See [Removed Functions](https://github.com/elm/compiler/blob/master/upgrade-docs/0.19.md#functions-removed).

Comment: The list of Removed Functions for Elm 0.19.0 has moved to [here](https://github.com/elm/compiler/blob/master/docs/upgrade-instructions/0.19.0.md#functions-removed).

Answer (score 3):

Flip was removed from elm/core in `0.19`. You could try:
[pilatch/flip](https://package.elm-lang.org/packages/pilatch/flip/latest/) package instead.

Comment: The elm-community/basics-extra package also includes this function: https://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm-community/basics-extra/latest/Basics-Extra#flip